# FLUENT-BIT: [io_tls] flb_io_tls.c:359 X509 - Certificate verification failed, e.g. CRL, CA or signature check

Tags: macos, amazon-s3, fluent-bit

I am trying to push the logs from MacBook pro to s3 using fluent-bit, but getting the following error.

```
[2020/12/01 03:17:00] [error] [io_tls] flb_io_tls.c:359 X509 - Certificate verification failed, e.g. CRL, CA or signature check
[2020/12/01 03:17:00] [error] [aws_client] connection initialization error
[2020/12/01 03:17:00] [error] [output:s3:s3.0] PutObject request failed
[2020/12/01 03:17:00] [error] [output:s3:s3.0] Cloud not send all chunks on exit
```

I tried to generate a certificate or disable TLS but still getting the same error

Comment: Please show your relevant configurations also to get better responses.